# Losing context with parse.com javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, scope

So the goal of what I'm doing it to store an array of objects inside an object literal for later reference. I am losing context(if that is the right terminology to use here) in a place that is confusing for me. Here is the code:

```
HuntObject = {

        // Data.hunts gives collection
        Data: {},

        fetchCollec: function(){
            var self = this;

            var huntObj = new Parse.Query(huntObject);
            huntObj.find({
                success: function(results){
                    var hunts = [];

                    for(i in results){
                        hunts.push(i);
                    }
                    console.log(self);
                            //Here self references HuntObject
                    self.Data = hunts;



                },

                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });

            console.log(self);// Here self references HuntObject 
                            console.log(self.Data); // empty
```

So in both my console.log statements the correct context that I want is referenced and in the last log call to self I can even see in the console that the Data object now has an array of objects in it. But than as soon as I try to reference that array I get an empty Object. I tried assigning the array in different ways like self.Data.array = hunts. I also tried to set up Data as a method like this.

```
Data: (function(){
        return {
            array: []
        }
     }());
```

I think maybe my understanding of how context changes in different situations is pretty weak so It would be nice to solve my original goal but more important I would like to understand context better and why my implementation is failing in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a scope or context issue, you're handling that with your `self` variable.

My guess is that `Parse.Query` is *asynchronous*. And so you'd have to do your `console.log` *within* the success function; doing it in the code immediately after the call to `Parse.Query` calls it too soon (before the query completes).

So:

```
huntObj.find({
    success: function (results) {
        var hunts = [];

        for (i in results) {
            hunts.push(i);
        }
        console.log(self);
        //Here self references HuntObject
        self.Data = hunts;

        // *********** Move these here
        console.log(self); // Here self references HuntObje
        console.log(self.Data); // Not empty anymore
    },

    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});

// Any code here runs after you've *started* the query, but
// before it *completes*
```

Comment: Oh duh haha i feel like an idiot. Ya your right I just added a callback and was able to do what I wanted. Thanks for the help.